# ProcessRequest invoked 3 times per request

Tags: asp.net

For some reason I'm experiencing that ProcessRequest is invoked 3 times per browser request in my HttpHandler. I'm using this to fetch documents from a database, and send them to the client. It's setup so every request to www.site.dk/documents/* is processed by this HttpHandler.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to look at which verbs you're handling (if you've specified * for your verbs, you might be getting separate calls for HEAD and GET, which would be two of the calls)

Also, you don't say what kind of documents you're serving up. If they're e.g. html documents, they may include references to other resources. If those resource URLs are relative, then those requests may also come into the /documents/* area.

Comment: Yeah specifying * for the verbs caused the problem. Thanks :)